# Passing the value of current field to custom validation function in Laravel

Tags: php, validation, laravel-8

I want to pass the value of the current field to a custom validation function in a Request class in my Laravel project.

I have tried the following:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'id'=>'required',
        //'type'=>'required|in:Attachment,Audio,Book,Picture,Video',
        'type'=>['required', $this->validateFileType()],
        //'type'=>[new Enum(FileType::class)], # only available on PHP 8.1+
        'soft_price' => 'numeric|min:1000',
        'hard_price' => 'numeric|min:1000',
    ];
}

public function validateFileType($type){

    $file_types = ['Attachment', 'Audio', 'Book', 'Picture', 'Video'];

    if(in_array($type, $file_types))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

and I get the following error:

```
"Too few arguments to function App\\Http\\Requests\\FileUpdateRequest::validateFileType(), 0 passed in C:\\xampp\\htdocs..."
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at [Custom Validation Rules](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#custom-validation-rules).

You can add a custom rule Class with artisan:

```
php artisan make:rule MyFileType
```

In it, you can access the current value and also output custom error messages

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    $file_types = ['Attachment', 'Audio', 'Book', 'Picture', 'Video'];
    
    if(in_array($value, $file_types))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

You use it in your code like this:

```
use App\Rules\MyFileType;

public function rules()
{
    return [
        ...
        'type' => ['required', new MyFileType],
        ...
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Although I had to: in_array($value, $file_types)

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Create new rule:

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class FileTypeRule implements Rule
{
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $file_types = ['Attachment', 'Audio', 'Book', 'Picture', 'Video'];

        if(in_array($file_types, $value))
           return true;
        else
           return false;
    }
}
```

Use it in the Request Rules method:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'id'=>'required',
        'type'=>['required', new FileTypeRule()],
        'soft_price' => 'numeric|min:1000',
        'hard_price' => 'numeric|min:1000',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to pass two arguments in the rules function and for more information please have look [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#custom-validation-rules)